# Strange behaviour for \newcolumntype and S column of package siunitx

Tags: siunitx

### **EDIT**

My original question contained two questions.  Ulrike Fischer (and afterwards Joseph Wright) were able, to address the first question concerning the usage of `\newcolumntype` in conjunction with a `S` column of package `siunitx`.  I suggested to edit to focus on that particular question.

The [other question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597828/different-results-in-s-columns-using-equivalent-options) will be discussed in its own thread.

The edited text below is now focused on the question, how to define new columntypes.

---

I want to display numbers in a tabular environment, using the package `siunitx` and its `S` column.

My original plan was, to use `\newcolumntype`, to define a new column `d` and give it two parameters, to gain more flexibility.  But I failed, LaTeX wasn't even able to compile but aborted with TeX capacity exceeded.

Here is an MWE with three flavours of the same tabular.  The first and second example do compile, see the results in the image below.

The third iteration doesn't compile at all :-(  Hence, I put the comments in place, to make it a **working** example.  Remove them, if you want to suffer with me.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% For headings
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\scriptsize}c}

%% New column types, using the S column of package siunitx
%% d-column: #1 ist the number of integers, #2 is the number of decimals
\newcolumntype{d}[2]{S[table-figure-integer=#1, table-figure-decimal=#2]}
%% f-column: #1 is the number of integers, the decimals are 2 digits fixed.
\newcolumntype{f}[1]{S[table-figure-integer=#1, table-fiugre-decimal=2]}
%% e-column, same as above, but with automated rounding.
\newcolumntype{f}[1]{S[table-figure-integer=#1, table-fiugre-decimal=2, table-auto-round]}


\begin{document}

%% This works.  
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}
  lr
  S[table-format=4.5]
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=4.2, table-auto-round=true]
  @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
  & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
  1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
  123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
  .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
  1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
  -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

%% This works kind of!  The second S column is wider than above.  The
%% last column is not rounded to 2 decimal places :-(
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}
  lr
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=5]
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=2]
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=2, table-auto-round=true]
  @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
  & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
  1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
  123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
  .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
  1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
  -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

%% Now, lets try the new defined d, e and f column.
%% This does not even compile!  TeX capacity exceeded!
% \begin{tabular}{%
%   @{}
%   lr
%   d{4}{5}
%   e{4}
%   f{4}
%   @{}}
%   \toprule
%   \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
%   \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
%   & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
%   \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r} 
%   & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}} 
%   & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
%   \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
%   1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
%   123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
%   .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
%   1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
%   -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
%   \bottomrule
% \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: Comparison between two identical tabulars]

The file was compiled by TeXLive 2021, using `siunitx` v2.8e, last revised 2021-04-17.

What went wrong?

Is there any way, to avoid the hassle of writing `S[long lists of options and values]` into the declaration of an tabular environment, as I intended the three new column letters `d`, `e` and `f` to be?

Comment: Why it it not correct?

Comment: @Bernard I have added a picture of the output.  Please compare the different behaviours of the two tables.  On page 48 of the manual it is said, that `table-format=3.2` should be "equivalent" to `table-figures-integer=3, table-figures-decimal=2`.  In my case it is 4.2, but as you can see, it is by far **not** equivalent!  Look at the second last column in the second table.  It should have only two digits, but shows up to five digits.  Look at the last column.  It was declared to `table-auto-round`, but it doesn't round the values to two digits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem with your last example is that you are defining column types which use chars which are then again in the inner column description. That means: the x column here is okay, but o breaks as "format" contains an o.

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype {x}{S[table-format=2.4]} %works
\newcolumntype {o}{S[table-format=2.4]}%breaks if used

\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{x}
   1.2345 
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

I normally prefer to use command tokens for column types:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\newcolumntype\intdec[2]{S[table-format=#1.#2]}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tabular}{\intdec{2}{4}}
   1.2345 
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you.  As far, as I understood, any column-letter, that is part of the declaration, would cause the problem, as it will be expanded with its declaration, which contains the declared column-letter, which will be expanded ... No wonder, TeXs capacity got exceeded.  But this is only half of the problem.  Why is the first table working as expected, but the second does not.  Why is in the first case, the  `e`-column with only 2 declared decimal places producing a column, which is to small, to fit all five decimals, whilst in the second example, the cloumn is wide enough to fit five decimals?

Comment: I didn't knew, that command tokens were allowed as column descriptors. :-)  Thank you for that insight.

Comment: Ulrike, I'd would like to suggest, that I will edit my question, to point the foucus of my question towards the `\newcolumntype` problem.  Then I would gladly mark your answer as solution to that particular question, which it undoubtly is and ask another question concerning the non-"equality" of `table-format` vs. `table-figures*`.  What do you think?

Comment: Focussing the question is fine

Comment: Question has been splitted. :-)

Comment: Your solution works fine for me.  Now my slides are presentable again.  Big Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

With v3 you can use the documented interface to create new column types. This avoids the fact that `S[...]` somewhat messes with the standard `array` syntax, which gets confused by options using letters from keys:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,final]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% For headings
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\scriptsize}c}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \jan_newcolumntype:nnn #1#2#3
  {
    \newcolumntype {#1} [#2]
      {
        > { \keys_set:nn { siunitx } {#3} \siunitx_cell_begin:w }
        c
        < { \siunitx_cell_end: }
      }
  }

%% New column types, using the S column of package siunitx
%% d-column: #1 ist the number of integers, #2 is the number of decimals
\jan_newcolumntype:nnn { d } { 2 }
  { table-format = #1.#2 }
%% f-column: #1 is the number of integers, the decimals are 2 digits fixed.
\jan_newcolumntype:nnn { f } { 1 }
  { table-format = #1.2 ] }
%% e-column, same as above, but with automated rounding.
\jan_newcolumntype:nnn { e } { 1 }
  { table-format = #1.2 , table-auto-round }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

%% Now, lets try the new defined d, e and f column.
%% This does not even compile!  TeX capacity exceeded!
 \begin{tabular}{%
   @{}
   lr
   d{4}{5}
   e{4}
   f{4}
   @{}}
   \toprule
   \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
   \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
   & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
   \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r} 
   & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}} 
   & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
   \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
   1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
   123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
   .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
   1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
   -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
   \bottomrule
 \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `-` symbol is wider than  a number, so you really need to allow for it in the table format.

Comment: Thanks, for the reply and solution.  Thank you also for reminding us on the effect of a missing `-`.  I am giving lectures on LaTeX.  The second `S` column was intentionally defined too small, to show, what happens in those cases.