# Different results in S columns using "equivalent" options

Tags: siunitx

### Note

This question was originally also contained in [another question of mine](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/597763/strange-behaviour-for-s-column-of-package-siunitx).  It was parted of, to have only one question per thread.

---

I want to display numbers in a tabular environment, using the package `siunitx` and its `S` column.

The actual manual says on page 48, that giving the option `table-format=4.2` should be equivalent to the much more elaborate version `table-figure-integer=4, table-figure-decimal=2`.  But I found out, that is not correct.

Here is an MWE with the two flavours.  They should result in identical looking tables, which is obviously not the case.

The first example works more or less as expected, i.e. if you define only 2 decimal places and insert numbers with more than 2 places, you get an `overfull hbox` error.  (This overfilling was done on educational purposes!  I know, that you have to give enough room, including positive or negative signs, etc., for LaTeX to be able, to produce a good looking table.)

The second iteration does compile, but gives "unexpected" results, as the column width will be computed correct, regardless of the number of digits you defined.  Please notice also, that there is no automatic rounding in the last column, despite the fact, that it was declared for the last column.

```tex
\documentclass[11pt,final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% For headings
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\scriptsize}c}

\begin{document}

%% This works.  The overfull box in the second S column 
%% is educationally intended!
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}
  lr
  S[table-format=4.5]
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=4.2, table-auto-round=true]
  @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
  & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
  1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
  123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
  .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
  1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
  -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

%% This works kind of!  The second S column is wider than above/wider than 
%% defined in the declaration.  The last column is not rounded to 2 
%% decimal places, as was also declared!
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}
  lr
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=5]
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=2]
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=2, table-auto-round=true]
  @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
  & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}} 
  & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
  1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
  123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
  .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
  1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
  -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Here is the result.

[image: These tables should be identical, but are not.]

Again: what went wrong.  Why does `table-format` succeed, where `table-figures-*` fails.  Why does the requested `table-auto-round` have no obvious effect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

table-format not only sets the numbers, but also `table-alignment-mode=format`

If I add this your tabulars are identical (this is compiled with version 3, and I removed inputenc as it is unneeded in a current latex)

```
\documentclass[11pt,final]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}

%% For headings
\newcolumntype{H}{>{\scriptsize}c}

\begin{document}

%% This works.  The overfull box in the second S column
%% is educationally intended!
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}
  lr
  S[table-format=4.5]
  S[table-format=4.2]
  S[table-format=4.2, table-auto-round=true]
  @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
  & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r}
  & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
  1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
  123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
  .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
  1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
  -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

%% This works kind of!  The second S column is wider than above/wider than
%% defined in the declaration.  The last column is not rounded to 2
%% decimal places, as was also declared!
\begin{tabular}{%
  @{}
  lr
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=5,table-alignment-mode=format]
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=2,table-alignment-mode=format]
  S[table-figures-integer=4, table-figures-decimal=2, table-auto-round=true,table-alignment-mode=format]
  @{}}
  \toprule
  \multicolumn{5}{@{}H@{}}{Columntype} \\
  \multicolumn{2}{@{}H}{normal}
  & \multicolumn{3}{H@{}}{siunitx} \\
  \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{l} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{r}
  & \multicolumn{1}{H}{d\{4\}\{5\}} & \multicolumn{1}{H}{e\{2\}}
  & \multicolumn{1}{H@{}}{f\{2\}} \\
  \cmidrule(r){1-2} \cmidrule(lr){3-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-4} \cmidrule(l){5-5}
  1.2345 & 1.2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 & 1,2345 \\
  123.45 & 123.45 & 123,45 & 123,45 & 123,45 \\
  .12345 & .12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 & ,12345 \\
  1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234   & 1234 \\
  -123   & -123   & -123   & -123   & -123 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks again.  You are faster than light! :-)